# How to extract data from file using only python

Tags: python, awk, text-processing

I have a data file which looks like::

```
# GROMACS
#
@    title "GROMACS Energies"
@    xaxis  label "Time (ps)"
@    yaxis  label "(K)"
@TYPE xy
@ view 0.15, 0.15, 0.75, 0.85
@ legend on
@ legend box on
@ legend loctype view
@ legend 0.78, 0.8
@ legend length 2
@ s0 legend "Temperature"
    0.000000  301.204895
    1.000000  299.083496
    2.000000  293.100250
    3.000000  301.090637
    4.000000  293.024811
    5.000000  297.068481
    6.000000  298.065125
    7.000000  300.354370
    8.000000  304.322693
    9.000000  297.093170
   10.000000  297.186615
   11.000000  298.112732
   12.000000  293.396545
   13.000000  295.803162
   14.000000  293.432037
   15.000000  298.306702
   16.000000  297.545715
   17.000000  294.283875
   18.000000  295.527771
   19.000000  297.193665
```

What I want to do is extract all of the data points below the `@ s0 legend "Temperature"` expression and put it in a dataframe, or simply a data structure which can be accessed easily by python.  I am using a combination of awk and python to do this at the moment.

I first do
`awk '/@ s0 legend/{flag=1; next} flag' temp.xvg > temp.dat`
to get the temp.dat file which has only the two columns of data. then, I use panda `read_csv` to get the data as columns to perform my analysis.

I want to cut the middleman of writing a temporary file to disk to send information to python. Is this possible? Can I extract the columns of data via a simple python script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a one-liner in python.  Something like:

```
file_data = [list(map(float,x.strip().split())) for x in open("filedata.txt","rt") if x.strip()[:1] not in "@#"]
```

Read in the file, strip whitespace, eliminate non-data lines, split string, convert to floats.  Result is a list of data pairs.

Answer (score 2):

You can just read lines from the file until you get to the `legend` line; then use `read_csv` on the balance of the file. While reading the lines at the beginning, you could also extract the xaxis and yaxis labels to use as column names. For example:

```py
import pandas as pd
import re

with open('test.dat', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        m = re.search(r'xaxis\s+label\s+"([^"]+)"', line)
        if m is not None:
            xaxis = m.group(1)
        m = re.search(r'yaxis\s+label\s+"([^"]+)"', line)
        if m is not None:
            yaxis = m.group(1)
        if line.startswith('@ s0 legend'):
            break
    df = pd.read_csv(f, names=[xaxis, yaxis], delim_whitespace=True)
    f.close()
    
print(df)
```

Output

```
    Time (ps)         (K)
0         0.0  301.204895
1         1.0  299.083496
2         2.0  293.100250
3         3.0  301.090637
4         4.0  293.024811
5         5.0  297.068481
6         6.0  298.065125
7         7.0  300.354370
8         8.0  304.322693
9         9.0  297.093170
10       10.0  297.186615
11       11.0  298.112732
12       12.0  293.396545
13       13.0  295.803162
14       14.0  293.432037
15       15.0  298.306702
16       16.0  297.545715
17       17.0  294.283875
18       18.0  295.527771
19       19.0  297.193665
```

Answer (score 0):

In python the equivalent program is:

```py
import re
# Using readlines()
file1 = open('temp.xvg', 'r')
Lines = file1.readlines()
 
count = 0
# Strips the newline character
for line in Lines:
    if count==0:
        x=re.search("^@ s0 legend",line)
        if x: # FOUND!!!
            count += 1

    else:
        print("{}".format(line.strip()))
```

You can save it as `program.py`. And then execute:

```sh
python2 program.py
```

You'll get this output:

```
0.000000  301.204895
1.000000  299.083496
2.000000  293.100250
3.000000  301.090637
4.000000  293.024811
5.000000  297.068481
6.000000  298.065125
7.000000  300.354370
8.000000  304.322693
9.000000  297.093170
10.000000  297.186615
11.000000  298.112732
12.000000  293.396545
13.000000  295.803162
14.000000  293.432037
15.000000  298.306702
16.000000  297.545715
17.000000  294.283875
18.000000  295.527771
19.000000  297.193665
```